# CFDocument PDF rendering issue with japanese

Tags: coldfusion, fonts, localization, cfdocument

Having some issue with Japanese font in **cfdocument**.

The fonts are correctly coming up but they are being **stretched** (word wraps not working) and taking up extra space and hence breaking the design in the pdf file.

The HTML content used in **cfdocument** is rendering correctly, also same is working correctly for Chinese and Korean fonts in the PDF file as well.

Let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: Aswin - you will probably need to show a sample of the CSS or formatting you are  using.

Comment: Have fixed the word wrap issue using coldfusion wrap function

[link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_t-z_16.html)

Comment: @AswinPrasanth you should add your fix as an answer to this question so others can find it more easily.  It is okay to answer your own questions here.  Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word wrap issue was fixed by adding ColdFusion [wrap function](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/functions_t-z_16.html).

Comment: The above documentation link is for CF8. Here's the link for the [CF9 wrap function documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7114.html).