# Wrap fails for HTML content

Tags: html, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I have tried to wrap HTML CMS content, but it fails.

Here the code I have tried:

```
<h3>Wrap Example</h3>
<cfset test='<h4><span>This is failure wrap function</span></h4><span><h5>This is failure wrap function</h5></span>'>
<cfoutput>#Wrap(test, 10)#</cfoutput>
```

The result is given below:

```
 Wrap Example

 This is failure wrap function< /span>

 This is failure wrap function< /h5>
```

How can fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [its docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/wrap.html), `wrap()` operates on a **string**, not a *fragment of HTML*. Whilst the latter is the former, the former does not imply any understanding of the latter. All `wrap()` sees is string data... it does not know that some of the string you are passing it is HTML, and accordingly one cannot simply interrupt an HTML tag with a line break character.

So basically there's nothing to "fix" here, as you're just using the inappropriate tool for the job.

I *suspect* what you should be looking at doing is putting the text within a `span` or a `div` or some other container tag, and then style that containing tag to have the width that you want. Chopping the string up into numbers-of-characters is not really how to approach the task you're wanting to accomplish, I think?

Why is it you're trying to do, in "wrapping" this mark-up at 10 characters?

Comment: I have added this for an example("wrapping" this mark-up at 10 characters). Thanks for your information. I got it

Comment: But word wrapping using css will not work while rendering html to pdf. You can check the same in the issue [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483073/cfdocument-pdf-rendering-issue-with-japanese](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483073/cfdocument-pdf-rendering-issue-with-japanese)

Comment: `<cfdocument>` ain't that good at doing PDFs, unfortunately. Odd, given who owns both ColdFusion and Acrobat.

Comment: You might need to raise another question relating to getting text-wrapping in both HTML and PDF working, perhaps? I cannot help you with that though, sorry. I know know anything about generating PDFs (other than stuff I taught myself when helping you with the Japanese stuff earlier)